# Python Text to Data Frame with Specific Pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a bunch of text files into a data frame using Pandas.

Thanks to Stack Overflow's amazing community, I almost got the desired output (OP: [Python Text File to Data Frame with Specific Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262170/python-text-file-to-data-frame-with-specific-pattern/68262491)).

Basically I need to turn a text with specific patterns (but sometimes missing data) into a data frame using Pandas.

Here is an example:

```
Number 01600 London                           Register  4314

Some random text...

************************************* B ***************************************
 1 SHARE: 73/1284
   John Smith
   BORN: 1960-01-01 ADDR: Streetname 3/2   1000
   f 4222/2001
   h 1334/2000
   i 5774/2000
 4 SHARE: 58/1284
   Boris Morgan
   BORN:            ADDR: Streetname 4   2000
 5 SHARE: 23/1284
   James Klein
   BORN:            ADDR:      
   c 4222/1988 Supporting Text
   f 4222/2000 Extra Text
************************************* C ***************************************
More random text...
```

From the example above, I need to transform the text between ***B*** and ***C*** into a data frame with the following output:

| Number | Register | City | Id | Share | Name | Born | Address | c | f | h | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01600 | 4314 | London | 1 | 73/1284 | John Smith | 1960-01-01 | Streetname 3/2 1000 | NaN | 4222/2001 | 1334/2000 | 5774/2000 |
| 01600 | 4314 | London | 4 | 58/1284 | Boris Morgan | NaN | Streetname 4 2000 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01600 | 4314 | London | 5 | 23/1284 | James Klein | NaN | NaN | 4222/1988 Supporting Text | 4222/2000 Extra Text | NaN | NaN |

Some of the patterns:

- The first row for the group contains the word SHARE; before this word is the `Id` and after it is the `Share`.
- The second row contains the name of the person (and should be extracted entirely to the `Name` variable).
- The third row contains the birthdate (BORN) and the address (ADDR). Sometimes this information is missing - in these cases, the variables `Born` and `Address` should be NaN.
- When it exists, the fourth row and beyond (which lasts until the next group is reached) starts with a lowercase letter. Each of these rows should be extracted until the end of the paragraph to a variable with the name being the leading lowercase letter.

The code below works when the birthdate and address are available, and when the fourth row and beyond contains only one chunk of information (in the previous example, SHARE: 73/1284 from John Smith has rows f, h and i - all with only one chunk of information and SHARE: 23/1284 from James Klein contains multiple chunks).

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''Number 01600 London                           Register  4314

Some random text...

************************************* B ***************************************
 1 SHARE: 73/1284
   John Smith
   BORN: 1960-01-01 ADDR: Streetname 3/2   1000
   f 4222/2001
   h 1334/2000
   i 5774/2000
 4 SHARE: 58/1284
   Boris Morgan
   BORN:            ADDR: Streetname 4   2000
 5 SHARE: 23/1284
   James Klein
   BORN:            ADDR:      
   c 4222/1988 Supporting Text
   f 4222/2000 Extra Text
************************************* C ***************************************
More random text...'''

text = [i.strip() for i in text.splitlines()] # create a list of lines

data = []

# extract metadata from first line
number = text[0].split()[1]
city = text[0].split()[2]
register = text[0].split()[4]

# create a list of the index numbers of the lines where new items start
indices = [text.index(i) for i in text if 'SHARE' in i]
# split the list by the retrieved indexes to get a list of lists of items
items = [text[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])][1:]

for i in items:
    d = {'Number': number, 'Register': register, 'City': city, 'Id': int(i[0].split()[0]), 'Share': i[0].split(': ')[1], 'Name': i[1], 'Born': i[2].split()[1], }
    items = list(s.split() for s in i[3:])
    merged_items = []

    for i in items:
        if len(i[0]) == 1 and i[0].isalpha():
            merged_items.append(i)
        else:
            merged_items[-1][-1] = merged_items[-1][-1] + i[0]
    d.update({name: value for name,value in merged_items})
    data.append(d)

#load the list of dicts as a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Does anyone know how to fix these issues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the same variable `i` for both inner and outer loops. Changing your `for` loop to the following should work cleaner:

```
for i in items:
    d = {'Number': number, 
         'Register': register, 
         'City': city, 
         'Id': int(i[0].split()[0]), 
         'Share': i[0].split(': ')[1], 
         'Name': i[1], 
         }
    
    if "ADDR" in i[2]:
        born, address = i[2].split("ADDR:")
        d['Born'] = born.replace("BORN:", "").strip()
        d['Address'] = address.strip()
    else:
        d['Born']: i[2].split()[1]
    
    if len(i)>3:
        for j in i[3:]:
            key, value = j.split(" ", 1)
            d[key] = value
    data.append(d)

#load the list of dicts as a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the list to include only the relevant values by getting the index numbers of the delimiter lines:

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''Number 01600 London                           Register  4314

Some random text...

************************************* B ***************************************
 1 SHARE: 73/1284
   John Smith
   BORN: 1960-01-01 ADDR: Streetname 3/2   1000
   f 4222/2001
   h 1334/2000
   i 5774/2000
 4 SHARE: 58/1284
   Boris Morgan
   BORN:            ADDR: Streetname 4   2000
 5 SHARE: 23/1284
   James Klein
   BORN:            ADDR:      
   c 4222/1988 Supporting Text
   f 4222/2000 Extra Text
************************************* C ***************************************
More random text...'''

text = [i.strip() for i in text.splitlines()] # create a list of lines

# extract metadata from first line
number = text[0].split()[1]
city = text[0].split()[2]
register = text[0].split()[4]

# get index numbers of delimiter values and filter list
start, end = [text.index(i) for i in text if '*****' in i]
text = text[start+1:end]

data = []

# create a list of the index numbers of the lines where new items start
indices = [text.index(i) for i in text if 'SHARE' in i]
# split the list by the retrieved indexes to get a list of lists of items
items = [text[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])][1:]

for i in items:
    d = {'Number': number, 'Register': register, 'City': city, 'Id': int(i[0].split()[0]), 'Share': i[0].split(': ')[1], 'Name': i[1], 'Born': i[2].split()[1] if i[2].split()[1][:4].isnumeric() else None}
    items = list(s.split() for s in i[3:])
    merged_items = []

    for i in items:
        if len(i[0]) == 1 and i[0].isalpha():
            merged_items.append([i[0], ' '.join(i[1:])])
        else:
            merged_items[-1][-1] = merged_items[-1][-1] + i[0]
    d.update({name: value for name,value in merged_items})
    data.append(d)

#load the list of dicts as a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | Number | Register | City | Id | Share | Name | Born | f | h | i | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01600 | 4314 | London | 1 | 73/1284 | John Smith | 1960-01-01 | 4222/2001 | 1334/2000 | 5774/2000 | nan |
| 1 | 01600 | 4314 | London | 4 | 58/1284 | Boris Morgan |  | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 01600 | 4314 | London | 5 | 23/1284 | James Klein |  | 4222/2000 Extra Text | nan | nan | 4222/1988 Supporting Text |

Comment: Thanks once again RJ Adriaansen. It almost worked as expected - for the lowercase letter variables (f, h, i, c), I need to take the the whole content after the lowercase letter - so for James Klein the variable ```c``` should contain: "4222/1988 Supporting Text" and ```f``` "4222/2000 Extra Text". As the word length of these rows can change, it should always take until the end of the row.